# I am trying to make a formula in excel using if blank statement for multiple cells. Possibly two different arguments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-statements, arguments

My current formula is `=IF(ISBLANK(J2),M2*AB2, IF(J2>1, AC2))`

Important to note my formula in M2 is `=IF(ISBLANK(L2),"",L2-G2)`

```
AB2=250    AC2= 550
```

The code runs as G2 gets a delivery date If J2 is blank and L2 has a date, M2 will multiply the amount of days by a dollar amount from AB2. If J2 has a date and L2 does not then the dollar amount from AC2 will calculate. this runs correctly but my value if both J2 and L2 are empty is #VALUE.

I want to put in a statement that solves the value. If both J2 and L2 are blank the value is 0. While keeping the other statements.

The attempts i have tried result in "there are too many arguments".

TLDR:

G2 has a date. If J2 and L2 are blank the value is zero. If J2 has a date and L2 does not then the value is AC2. If J2 does not have a date and L2 does than M2*AB2

Excel formula:

[image: Excel formula]

Comment: Your first formula `IF(J2>1, AC2)` is perhaps missing an "else" value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the formula `=IFS(AND(J2="",L2=""),"",AND(J2<>"",L2=""),AC2,AND(J2="",L2<>""),M2*AB2)`

Comment: Yes this solved it thank you !